# ¿Se puede generar un loop con un Timer0 en Pic C Compiler?

Tags: c, timer

Estoy realizando un proyecto, se trata un juego donde mi programa elige una figura de cierto color y yo tengo que colocar la figura en dos orificios. El 1° verifica si el color que yo coloco coincide con el color pedido por el programa, el 2° verifica si estoy colocando la figura que me pide en el orificio correcto del gabinete.

Una vez que acierte dentro de unos 10 seg, el programa sigue adelante. Pero si fallo el programa tiene que volver a repetir esos 10 segundos esperando a que se coloque la figura con el color que se me pide.

Utilizo un pic que con un oscilador interno de 8MHz :) No tengo mucha mano con el lenguaje C, pero me lo pide la escuela! Si alguno pudiera aportar alguna estructura para generar esto con el timer0 se lo agradecería mucho!

No estoy segura de que función utilizar para realizar la vuelta al inicio del timer. Mi prioridad es utilizar una función que me ayude a realizar algún loop.

Lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora es esto:

```
SET_TIMER0(236);
if((red > redmin) && (red < redmax)) // Si toma las frecuencias del color seleccionado (ROJO)
{
   generate_tone(C_NOTE[1],800), generate_tone(D_NOTE[1],800), generate_tone(E_NOTE[1],800); // Se genera música WIN
   delay_ms(2000);
} //LIMPIAR TIMER
else
{
  generate_tone(E_NOTE[1],800), generate_tone(D_NOTE[1],800),generate_tone(C_NOTE[1],800); // CASO CONTRARIO: Se genera música FAIL
  delay_ms(2000);
  //ACÁ TENDRÍA QUE VOLVER AL SETTIMER
}
```

Comment: Bienvenida. ¿Qué intentaste? Me refiero al código.

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y proveas un [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y podamos ayudarte. Debes colocar el código de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Puedes editar tu pregunta haciendo click en [edit]. Saludos!

Comment: @Mateo disculpame si no se entiende mucho jajajaj, recién estoy aprendiendo a poner los formatos de letras en los comentarios. Cualquier cosa si necesitas ver algo más pedimelo. Aclaro que creo que en ese entonces hice mal la cuenta y puse en el set_timer0 el nro 156, después lo verifico. Mi prioridad es generar una sintaxis que me ayude jaja :(

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta con esa información, como te lo mencionó @Andres.